# Android: What's the difference between a boolean for a click and button.isPressed()?

Tags: android, boolean, onclicklistener

There are a lot of options on how to define a click/tap on the touchscreen. One of them for example is setting a boolean.

**Example for boolean:**

```
boolean buttonClicked = true;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (buttonClicked) {
                 //do that and this
                }
            }
        });
```

**And there's a `isPressed()` method:**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (button.isPressed()) {
                     //do that and this
                    }
                }
            });
```

What exactly is the difference between them? And **when** and **why** do I use boolean and the method `isPressed()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are referring to a button in both of your examples, I assume that you are referring to the user tapping on a button, not just a random touch on the screen.

That being said, both of the examples you provided are not good.

1. In your first example, the boolean is useless because it is always true, so `//do that and this` will always be reached.
2. In your second example, your `if` statement is useless, because the `onClick` method by its nature is only reached when the button is tapped.

A good way to listen for a button press is using a click listener like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Code placed here will run every time the button is tapped
    }
});
```

...where `R.id.buttonId` is the ID of your button in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to define click event for a View you can use **onClickListener**, **onTouchListener**. 
For more information check for Android official Documentation.

- [onTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)
- [onTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

When considering your first code snippet, You can use boolean to perform another operation on button click event. as example something like this ,

```
boolean buttonClicked = false;

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              //true after button clicked
               buttonClicked = true;
            }
        });

        //if buttonClicked equals true
        if (buttonClicked){
            //perform operation only after button clicked
        }
```

when considering your second code snippet, no need of `button.isPressed()` inside 
button's `onClick()` callback. Because what you want to do by checking `button.isPressed()` is done without it inside button's `onClick()` callback.

Keep in mind these things.

- `isPressed()` is a public method of `View` Class
- `Button` is a subclass of `View` Class
- `isPressed()` is a public method of `Button` Class as well.

---

**About** [isPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isPressed()) **from Android official documentation.**

> Indicates whether the view is currently in pressed state. Unless
>   setPressed(boolean) is explicitly called, only clickable views can
>   enter the pressed state.
>   Returns true if the view is currently pressed, false otherwise.